# Rules: how to email "last edited by" user

Tags: rules, workflows

I am using Rules for a node publishing workflow. When a node is in "needs review" status and an admin either rejects or publishes the draft, I'd like to notify the user who created the draft (i.e. not necessarily the node's author).

Comment: Are you using the Workflow or Workbench modules?  Or have you rolled your own solution using just Rules?

Comment: I am using Workbench + Workbench Moderation. I've successfully created rules to notify admins when a draft is set to "needs review", and I did set up a rule to notify the node author when a draft is rejected or published, but I'd really like to notify the person who made the draft. On a related note, isn't each draft a new node? So shouldn't the node author for a draft be the one who created the draft?